# VBA to run rules on messages within the last 2 weeks in Outlook 2013

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2013

I have millions of messages dating back to the first day of employment

When I implement this code

```
Session.DefaultStore.GetRules.Item("myRuleName").Execute
```

It executes it on all messages.

However I am only interested in executing this rule on messages within the last two weeks and only on a **`mailbox (shared) called "ITRequests.Mbx@example.com"`**

We are using Outlook 2013 with Exchange

---

I know how to get the current item(s) but how do I apply my rules to those specific mail items

```
 Sub MailItemByTime() 
 Dim aItem As Object
 Dim strTime As String

 Set mail = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
 For Each aItem In mail.Items

      'Check the message age
      If aItem.ReceivedTime > Date - 14 Then

      ' How to process these specific items ONLY????

 End If

 Next aItem

 Set aItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call a VBA sub from a rule where you may check out the target Outlook message (when it was received and etc.). The sub should be in the following format:

```
public sub Test(mail as MailItem)
    ' check out the mail object 
end sub
```

You may find the [ReceivedTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867228.aspx) property of the MailItem class helpful. It returns a Date indicating the date and time at which the item was received.

Comment: How can I run a rule on specific MailItems?